# ASP.NET claim policy not authorizing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4, claims-based-identity

I have set up a basic TestAdmin account to use claim based Authentication in a microservice app. I have the relevant code set up as follows:

```
await userManager.AddClaimAsync(testAdmin, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "NavInvoices"));
```

This shows up in the AspNetUserClaims db, so it is being created and saved.
I tried these two methods to set up the Policy(I have it only checking if any ClaimTypes.Role exists right now):

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("NavInvoices2", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role));
        });

services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("NavInvoices", policy =>
                policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
                    context.User.HasClaim(c =>
                        (c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role))));
        });
```

And this is the Controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "NavInvoices")]
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";


        return View();
    }
```

The problem is when I iterate over user.claims there is no role. Only things like email, name etc. In the SqlDB only my role I created exists. None of these other things that exist like name and email are in the DB. So there is a disconnect somewhere. I am using IdentityServer4's Quickstart EFandAspNetIdentity template as my base if anyone has familiarity with that.

I've googled everything I can and so far I can't find anything. I think there is two separate storages going on and the cookie is only passing one of them through to the webmvc project. Any suggestions?

Comment: Adding a role to the database doesn't automatically add a role to the claims. And not all claims are automatically mapped. Are you familiar with this article? https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/

Comment: Thank you for the article.Is this saying I should do 
    options.ClaimActions.MapUniqueJsonKey("role", "role");?

Comment: You don't have to map roles like that. But first make sure the roles are included as claims. You can use OpenIdConnectEvents to determine which claims are received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are including the claims in the identity token when you are passing it to your client.

The client configuration should have the following lines :-

```
  new Client
   {
     ClientId = "yourclient",
     ClientName = "Your Client",
     // left out for brevity
     AlwaysSendClientClaims = true, 
     AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true
   }
```

This should allow all of the users claims to pull through.

You can look at this question i answered earlier for further information, and to an example on my repo :-

[IdentityServer4 custom AuthenticationHandler can't find all claims for a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207770/identityserver4-custom-authenticationhandler-cant-find-all-claims-for-a-user/48210941#48210941)

Comment: I added those lines and still no luck. I will look at your previous answer and see if I can make it work.

Comment: I added everything from your previous answer by looking at the change logs on github. Still no luck. I'm not using roles and instead adding it directly to the user. Could that be an issue?

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: For anyone who sees this I needed to change await userManager.AddClaimAsync(testAdmin, new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "NavInvoices")); ---to--- await userManager.AddClaimAsync(testAdmin, new Claim("NavInvoices", "NavInvoices"));

Comment: @Gutsee Seems to me that ClaimTypes.Role is correct. You changed the server but you should have modified the client. If you look at the claims on the client you may notice that ClaimTypes.Role was replaced with another type, because of Microsoft known claims mapping. Clearing the inbound ClaimTypeMap may have solved this: JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear();

Comment: Thanks, for the comment. I already have that line in the code. (It is default in IdentityServer4 template)